Is it possible to make the actual background except the face transparent in unity arcore?
Through the AR function, we want to leave only the face area through the actual front camera of the smartphone and then make the rest of the area transparent.
Currently, the method of recognizing faces and applying a mask or object to the face has been applied.
When taking pictures with an actual smartphone camera, it doesn't work to make the rest of the area except the face transparent. I would like to ask if there is a way. help
I tried creating a material using shader code, but it failed.
There was no recognition of the background

The most effective method for achieving what you want is to create a custom shader. While the face tracking is already working correctly, you need to use a shader to make the background transparent when taking a photo. The shader can be set up to keep the face area visible while masking the rest. This way, when you press the photo capture button, only the face will be visible, and the background will be transparent.
You mentioned that you tried creating a shader before. Can you share how you wrote the shader code and where you encountered issues? Maybe a small adjustment or change can solve the problem. Additionally, you might have created the shader correctly, but did you ensure that the face detection is updating the mask in real-time and applying it to the shader? This step is crucial for the shader to work properly.
